# Get FALSE value when I insert data into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

When I just insert the username and password into my sql database, everything is okay but I get FALSE value when I try to add user's full name and company. I am not sure whether the way I bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters is correct or not. Can anyone please help me have a look on my code ? Thanks in advance!

```html
<?php
// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $full_name = $company = $password = $confirm_password = "";
$username_err = $full_name_err = $company_err =$password_err = $confirm_password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Validate username
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter a username.";
    } else{
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                /* store result */
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                    $username_err = "This username is already taken.";
                } else{
                    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }



     // Validate full name
    if(empty(trim($_POST["full_name"]))){
        $full_name_err = "Please enter your full name.";
    } else{
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE full_name = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_full_name);

            // Set parameters
            $param_full_name = trim($_POST["full_name"]);

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                /* store result */
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                    $full_name_err = "The name is already taken.";
                } else{
                    $full_name = trim($_POST["full_name"]);
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }


     // Validate company
    if(empty(trim($_POST["company"]))){
        $company_err = "Please enter your company.";
    } else{ $company = trim($_POST["company"]);}



    // Validate password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter a password.";     
    } elseif(strlen(trim($_POST["password"])) < 2){
        $password_err = "Password must have atleast 6 characters.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }


    // Validate confirm password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["confirm_password"]))){
        $confirm_password_err = "Please confirm password.";     
    } else{
        $confirm_password = trim($_POST["confirm_password"]);
        if(empty($password_err) && ($password != $confirm_password)){
            $confirm_password_err = "Password did not match.";
        }
    }


    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err) && empty($confirm_password_err)&& empty($full_name_err)&& empty($company_err)){

        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username,full_name, company, password) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
                        // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            $param_full_name = $full_name;
            $param_company = $company;
            $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash

            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $param_username,$param_full_name,$param_company, $param_password);

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Redirect to login page
                header("location: login.php");

            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
               // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }


    }  

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

Comment: I know that tutorial - and it's pretty bad, making the code look super complicated for no advantages whatsoever.

Comment: @Dragonsnap Do u have any other similar tutorial to suggest?